# htaccess redirects to /var/www/vhosts/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with htaccess redirects for url without /

Example
`example.com/somepage/` redirects to `https://example.com/somepage/` and thats fine

`example.com/somepage` redirects to `https://www.example.com/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/somepage/httpss:/www.example.com/somepage` and should redirects to `https://example.com/somepage/`

I have this rules in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/)?$ $1.html


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/)?$ $1.php


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
#RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.html?
#RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing and why I'm getting this strange redirect?

Comment: What does `somepage` refer to in your example? Is this your complete `.htaccess` file? Where is this `.htaccess` file located? "redirects to `https://example.com/somepage/`" - Do you mean `www.example.com`, as opposed to `example.com`? Whilst there are some errors in the rules you've posted, the resulting redirect you are seeing does not appear to be caused by the directives as posted? It looks like it could be a cached redirect from an earlier "erroneous" rule (that has since been "fixed")?

Comment: For example, if you had previously used `https%1://` (or `httpss://`) in your first rule then this could have resulted in this erroneous redirect (and it would have been cached, because of the 301). However, this would also seem to suggest that `/subpage` is a directory and this `.htaccess` file is in that subdirectory? Or do you have more than 1 `.htaccess` file?

Comment: 'some page' refer to folder where i have more files. Let's say that 'some page' is parent and the i have /some-page/child-items
I don't know if there were some old rules because I just got my hands on this website.
I have bunch of 301 redirects in .htaccess and some caching rules.